# Biblatex APA citation with parentheses

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

What style should I use to make the citations rendering as (Einstein, 1915)? Using `biblatex` on Overleaf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For real APA citations you want to use the package `biblatex-apa` (7th-edition APA style) or `biblatex-apa6` (6th-edition APA style).

With `biblatex-apa` use `style=apa,`. With `biblatex-apa6` you'd use `style=apa6,` in the example below.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite{worman}
It was shown by \textcite{nussbaum} that

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) ipsum (Worman, 2002) It was shown by Nussbaum (1978) that]

---

If you just want author-year citations and not necessarily all that APA style entails (some people call this class of styles "Harvard style"), you can use the standard `authoryear` style and customise it to your liking ([Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite{worman}
It was shown by \textcite{nussbaum} that

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Worman 2002) It was shown by Nussbaum (1978) that]

---

Independent of the exact details of the style, most `biblatex` styles print citations in parentheses if you use `\parencite`. Often it is preferable to use `\autocite` and configure it to produce citations in parentheses (this is usually the default for author-year styles).

Apart from `\autocite` and `\parencite` many `biblatex` styles define `\textcite`, which comes in handy in case you want to mention the author in your sentence.

Comment: I don't fully understand your example. You say to use `biblatex-apa` but in your example you're using just `biblatex`. Also, if I use `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}` citations appear without parentheses, i.e. Einstein, 1915 instead of (Einstein, 1015). Not working with `\parencite` also

Comment: @FedericoTaschin `biblatex-apa` is the name of the "bundle" that provides the APA style for `biblatex` that you can use with `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}`. As you can see in the screenshot both `\parencite` and `\autocite` produce parentheses for me with `style=apa,`. If that is not the case for you, please post a minimal working example that reproduces the incorrect behaviour (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).